# JFXtras Agenda Exceptions

Tags: eclipse, javafx-8, jfxtras

I have some Problems with the Agenda from the JFxtras lib, when I try to compile my Code. I get this Exceptions, It looks like there are some Problems with the CSS. I use the latest jar from the JFXtras Page "jfxtras-agenda.8.0-r3"

```
    Exception in Application start method
Nov 21, 2014 3:26:17 PM javafx.scene.control.Control impl_processCSS
SEVERE: The -fx-skin property has not been defined in CSS for Agenda@57948977[styleClass=Agenda] and createDefaultSkin() returned null.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$48/128893786.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jfxtras/scene/control/ImageViewButton
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.loadSkinClass(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control$4.invalidated(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.set(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control$4.set(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.applyStyle(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.applyStyle(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper.transitionToState(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Window$9.invalidated(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Window.show(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.show(Unknown Source)
    at application.Agenda1.start(Agenda1.java:305)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$66/705017936.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/1051754451.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/286278905.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/1775282465.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1109371569.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jfxtras.scene.control.ImageViewButton
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 41 more
Exception running application application.Agenda1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run your application with the `Agenda` custom control from JFXtras, besides `jfxtras-agenda-8.0-r3.jar` you need to add also to your classpath:

- jfxtras-common-8.0-r3.jar
- jfxtras-controls-8.0-r3.jar

Both are available at [Maven central](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/jfxtras/).